# Employees in g-suite appear as "Anonymous user" in hangouts chat

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-hangouts-chat

We use g-suite and use the old google hangouts. In an attempt to try out the new "[Hangouts Chat](https://gsuite.google.com/products/chat/)" Most of the employees appear as 'Anonymous User' to everyone else.  Only a tiny handful of employees appear as their actual name.  This occurs even in direct 1:1 conversations.

Anyone have a solution to this?

**edit:**
While comparing the employees that appear correctly vs "Anonymous User" we noticed anyone who enabled Google+ showed up correctly. Not a solution in our view since we can't force (nor do we want to) folks to enable social media.

Comment: Have you already submitted a support ticket to Google?

Comment: Not yet.  I'm hoping this is a simple answer.  I did find one conversation from March which thought the problem surrounded contact sharing.